# Spree Products API for a particular store - spree-multi-domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4, e-commerce, spree

I have an Spree application with spree-multi-domain extension support. Here their are different store with different products assigned to it.(in Admin panel)

like for STORE 1 domain is *store1.example.com* and for STORE 2 -> *store2.example.com*

Here I have set the wildcard subdomains for multiple store

> `*.example.com`

Okay now, when I call `example.com/api/products.json?token=MY_TOKEN_ID`,

I get complete list of products in JSON format. But
Here, I have a issue while retrieving products for Store 1 and Store 2 through api call.

When I call products.json for the

Store 1 `store1.example.com/api/products.json?token=MY_TOKEN_ID` and for

Store 2 `store2.example.com/api/products.json?token=MY_TOKEN_ID`

then also I get the complete list of products when as usual like `example.com/api/products.json?token=MY_TOKEN_ID`

What I'm expecting here is when I call the  GET request for products of a particular store then I should get the products of that particular store which was assigned in the admin panel.

So What should I do, couldn't understand.

Please help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the spree-multi-gem is not 100% stable and still under development.

you need to override the API and use current_store for each request.

> A new ControllerHelpers::Store concern provides a current_store helper to fetch a helper based on the request’s domain.

just an example, non related to api

create a **/app/controllers/spree/taxons_controller_decorator.rb** and extend the TaxonsController. you need to class_eval it, otherwise you override the complete class!!

```
Spree::TaxonsController.class_eval do
   def show
    @taxon = Spree::Taxon.find_by_store_id_and_permalink!(current_store.id, params[:id])
    return unless @taxon

    @searcher = build_searcher(params.merge(:taxon => @taxon.id))
    @products = @searcher.retrieve_products
    @taxonomies = get_taxonomies
  end
end
```

so by that, every other function from the Spree::TaxonsController stays as it was, and just the show method was overridden

so for your case: this is the orignal file

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/api/app/controllers/spree/api/v1/products_controller.rb

so you need to go into your rails app and have a **/app/controllers/spree/api/v1/products_controller_decorator.rb** where you go (i think that works)

```
Spree::Api::V1::ProductsController.class_eval do

end
```

but after reading that i think the best idea is to override
https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/715d4439f4f02a1d75b8adac74b77dd445b61908/api/app/controllers/spree/api/base_controller.rb#L132

Line 132 the `product_scope` :-)

this should help you - if not you better go magento :P

cheers

Comment: Thank you @huan son. Theoretically understood that I have to override the API but don't know how and where to do this. Can you please provide me some code or any starter way to get that done. And yes your answer helped me to next level.

Comment: that is pretty easy.
look into the spree code where the api is and just create that file(s) into your  own /app folder. rails is looking from the outside to the inside so  if there a file is called api_controller in a gem, first that one is loaded. if there is also one in your /app/api_controller then this is loaded. that is the way how to override.

with spree, you do a class_eval of that class and just override specified methods you need to.

Comment: i added an example for a controller classeval

Comment: I have the same spree demo project with different stores and products assigned to each particular stores.Sadly I'm not able to override the index method to get the current_store products. Could you please add the method for retrieving current_store products and respond in json. Please this would be very helpful